# Issue with including css to jsp in java application

Tags: java, css, jsp

I'm developing java application and I'm using bootstrap. When I use CDN url to obtain css it works ok. But I when I tried to add css localy it didn't found it.
My project structure: 
[image]

Maybe something with path?

Comment: from what I can see your path could be `../../css/bootstrap.css`. the `../` takes you up a directory, so going up two directories could to the trick.

Comment: @VictoriaS. I've tried that. It doesn't work

Comment: You can not access resource directly which are in WEB-INF. You can use a static resource handler. In java config For example, registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/"); or Put css outside of web-inf directory.

Comment: The above is correct. Move the CSS files under /webapp/css and you can then access them from your JSP relative to the root of the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who commented on my qyestion. So as I've searched for a correct structure of maven project with css and views I've learnt that all css/jsp/js should be located in webapp folder. best practise is to create "resources" folder and then add css/js/jsp in there. 
Something like this

```
webapp 
  |___WEB-INF
  |___resources
          |____css
          |____js
          |____jsp
```